# Dual values order with Cplex

Tags: c++, cplex

I am trying to get a dual values vector of a primal LP with getDuals(). I don't know in what order the dual variables will be returned. I found an example in Java that uses the HashMap. I want to know if there is any solution when using C++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IloCplex::getDuals expects an IloRangeArray as an input parameter and an IloNumArray.  As an output parameter.  IloRangeArray is ILOG's custom array type.

```
IloEnv env;
IloModel m(env);

int num_vars = ...;
IloRangeArray constraints(env, num_vars);
//  ...
// populate the constraints
// ...
m.add(constraints);
IloCplex cplex(m);
int retval cplex.solve();
// verify that cplex found a solution
if (!retval) //  ...

IloNumVarArray duals(env);
cplex.getDuals(duals, constraints);
```

IloRangeArray is ILOG concert's custom array type, which some feel is somewhat [dated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3443195/is-it-just-me-or-could-the-cplex-concert-api-use-some-improvements).  You are able to store IloRange objects in any data structure.  In that case, to get the duals, you need to use the `IloCplex::getDual` function.  For example, if you used a vector

```
IloEnv env;
IloModel m(env);

int num_vars = ...;
std::vector<IloRange> constraints(env, num_vars);
//  ...
// populate the constraints and add them to the model;

for (IloRange constr : constraints) 
   m.add(constr);
IloCplex cplex(m);
int retval cplex.solve();
// verify that cplex found a solution
if (!retval)  //  ...


vector<double> duals;
for (IloRange constr: constraints)
    duals.push_back(cplex.getDual(constr);
```

The IloRange objects are handles, so can be treated like smart pointers and stored in most of the standard data structures.